# Proper way of bind and render a collection view with router in Backbone.js + Require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

folks!

I've been working and messing around with Backbone.js + Require.js to build an app. In the app, I have the router and some views that are bounded to collections. the `render()` method of the views is triggered after a collection is synced.

So, here is what I did first:

### router.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/sampleCollection',
  'views/sampleView',
], function($, _, Backbone, SampleCollection, SampleView){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Define some URL routes
      '': 'home'
    },
    initialize: function(){ ... },
    home: function(){
      var home = new SampleView({collection: SampleCollection});    
    }  
});

(...)

});
```

### sampleCollection.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  '../models/SampleModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, SampleModel){

  var SampleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'url/to/api/call',
    model: SampleModel,
  });

  var sample_collection = new SampleCollection;
  sample_collection.fetch();

  // Our module now returns our collection
  return sample_collection;
});
```

### sampleView.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Using the Require.js text! plugin, we are loaded raw text
  // which will be used as our views primary template
  'text!templates/sample.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, SampleTemplate){
  var SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#main'),
    initialize: function(){
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
      this.sampleList = this.collection;
      
    },
    render: function(){
      // Using Underscore we can compile our template with data
      var data = { ... };
      var compiledTemplate = _.template( SampleTemplate, data );
      // Append our compiled template to this Views "el"
      this.$el.html( SampleTemplate );

      var string = '';

      this.sampleList.each(function(item){
        string += ('<div>data1: ' + item.get('data1') + ', data2: ' + data.get('data2') + ... +'</div>');
      });

      this.$el.append(string);

    }
  });

  // Our module now returns our view
  return SampleView;
});
```

At first, the route is triggered, `sync` is triggered from the collection and the view is rendered after listen to the `sync`. The problem is, when I change to another view, and come back to this view again, the view isn't rendered and `sync` is not triggered again, because the collection is fetched once inside **sampleCollection.js**.

To change it and make the view render every time I hit that route, I made these changes to the code:

### router.js (new)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/sampleCollection',
  'views/sampleView',
], function($, _, Backbone, SampleCollection, SampleView){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Define some URL routes
      '': 'home'
    },
    initialize: function(){ ... },
    home: function(){

      var sample_collection = new SampleCollection;
      sample_collection.fetch();

      var home = new SampleView({collection: sample_collection});    
    }  
});

(...)

});
```

... and...

### sampleCollection.js (new)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  '../models/SampleModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, SampleModel){

  var SampleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'url/to/api/call',
    model: SampleModel,
  });

  return SampleCollection;
});
```

Phew! That's a lot of code!

With those changes, now the view is rendered, because every time I hit the route, a new collection is fetched and triggers the `sync`. **But I don't know if this is the best way to do it, or there is a better approach for this**. Anyone have a suggestion for a better approach, or I'm doing it right?

Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't re-fecth the same collection again and again. But only when you need some new data from the server.

So if you want to re-render the list (a.k.a. `home`) each time the "home" route is triggered, simply `render()` home again (it already holds the data/the collection):

### router.js (new)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/sampleCollection',
  'views/sampleView',
], function($, _, Backbone, SampleCollection, SampleView){


  // Unique instances (private)
  var sample_collection = new SampleCollection,
      home = new SampleView({collection: sample_collection});

  sample_collection.fetch();

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Define some URL routes
      '': 'home'
    },
    initialize: function(){ ... },
    home: function(){

      // Whether it holds the data or not render the view.
      // It will be re-rendered anyway when `sync` will be triggered
      home.render();
    }  
  });

(...)

});
```

*Note*: `sample_collection` & `home` *should* probably be created only once.

Also, you might want to listen to `add`, `remove`, `reset` [events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) on your collection:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderOneItem); // To be defined
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.removeOneItem); // To be defined
```

Comment: Thanks, @8y5! I think that relying only at `sync` to render my view was the main mistake. I thought that rendering twice the view at the first time wasn't ok, but I thinkg that it's not a big deal, right?

Comment: No, it's not (a big deal). Mostly because your collection is empty the first time!